# Amazon key pair deleted

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I think I deleted serverside key pair by and now am getting:

```
Using username "ubuntu".
Server refused our key
```

I am running a Amazon EC2 server for my customer. How do I restore access to the server?

Comment: You can upload a new keypair and start a new server. (And I dort think you can delete the keypair of a running server in AWS)

Comment: @eckes my customer has data on existing server. I'm dead if I don't recover it. I ran `sudo rm *` by accident :((((

Comment: You can snapshot the Servers volume and attach that snapshot to the new server. Or you shutdown the server, mount its EBS volume to,another server then you can edit passwd and ssh config and start the volume again. Also it is a bad sign if a cloud image is this critical, that's a serious architecture problem.

Comment: As of ~2018/2019, you can login via Sessions Manager or EC2 Instance Connect. With these you can login without a keypair, allowing you to upload a new public key to the instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are unable to login to the Amazon EC2 instance, do not panic. All your data is safe!

The instance will need a new keypair loaded into the `/users/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_users` file.

This can be done in two ways:

- By creating a new instance that will trigger the automated mechanism that installed the key initially, or
- By copying a file onto that disk volume

**Method 1: Create a new instance**

This method makes an AMI (Amazon Machine Image) of your boot volume and launches a new Amazon EC2 instance from that image. This will trigger the same mechanism that is used to install a key when your instance was initially launched.

- Select your instance and select **Image > Create Image** from the **Actions** menu
- In the **AMIs** section of the console, wait until your instance is Running, then select it and choose **Launch**.
- Enter the configuration information (eg instance type, network)
- After clicking the final **Launch** button, choose a keypair

The boot process will recognize that it is running on a new Amazon EC2 instance (with a different `InstanceId`) and will copy your nominated keypair to the `authorized_users` file. You can then login.

**Method 2: Copy a keypair to the disk**

This method involves attaching the disk to another instance, copying the keypair, then booting it again.

- Stop your instance ("Instance A")
- Start another Amazon EC2 instance, or use an existing one if you already have it ("Instance B")
- Detach the EBS volume from Instance A
- Attach the EBS volume to Instance B
- Login to Instance B, access the newly-attached disk and copy a keypair to the `/users/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_users` file
- Reverse the above: Detach the EBS Volume, reattach it to Instance A, start Instance A
- Login and be happy

This is similar to the rather dated document: [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)

Comment: You saw the comment where the user ran `sudo rm *`?  D'oh.  Method 2 isn't going to take you very far.

Comment: Ah! Correct -- this is no longer a question of how to login, but of how to recover data on a Linux system.

Comment: My hands are shaking. Tried method 1 several times. In order to log into mysql i had to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5`. After that my  databases are gone. But before I closed the SSH session last night `mysql> show tables;` listed all tables. I even checked contents of few, all the data was there.

Comment: I'm terrified to stop the original instance as phpmyadmin is still responding, it just wont let me in

Comment: @JohnRotenstein if i create instance from AMI, does it affect the original instace? And instace created from AMI copies data, whatever i do in new instance doesn't affect AMI image, right?

Comment: When creating an AMI, there is a "No Reboot" option you can select. By default, the instance is rebooted so that the image is consistent, but you can check the "No Reboot" option to take the copy without stopping the original instance. It will boot up like you had pulled the power cord out of a computer without correctly shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can stop (not terminated) the server and make an image from it.
2. Then you can start a new server based on the image you just made. When you create the new server, you can create a new key pair.
3. Finally, you can log in the newly created server and use it as usual.